# how to show multiple toast notifications in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, notifications, toastr

I am trying to show multiple notifications with [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) but only first message is being shown.

```
return response()->json(array(
                             'status'=>'warning',
                             'message'=> 'Invoiced could not sent!',
                             'status'=>'success',
                             'message'=> 'item successfully modified!'
));
```

Output:

> { status: "success", message: "Booking successfully modified!" }
>
> message: "Booking successfully modified!"
>
> status: "success"

[image]

I would appreciate if you can tell me how to show multiple messages as in the above screenshot. some of the notifications might have a warning status and some might have a success status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're doing it is overriding the `status` and `message` properties of the array.

Consider creating an array of arrays for such a thing:

```
return response()->json(array(
    'messages' => array(
        array(
            'status'=>'warning',
            'message'=> 'Invoiced could not sent!'
        ),
        array(
            'status'=>'success',
            'message'=> 'item successfully modified!'
        )
    )
));
```

Then you can iterate over each element.

```
$.ajax({
    // Your current configuration
}).done(function (response) {
    for(var msg in response.messages) {
        var status = response.messages[msg]['status'];
        var message = response.messages[msg]['message'];
        toastr[status](message);
    } 
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I get only an empty error notification. I think the brackets are causing a problem but if I remove the brackets I get The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.error. Is there an another way that I can try?

Comment: I am sorry it didn't work either. I updated my question. added a output. you may have better idea how the current array looks like.

Comment: I added an example with Ajax and modified a bit the PHP code

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. It worked :)  I appreciate your help. All the best.